# Does opc ua sampling rate set at 0 work with an OPC UA Ecplise Milo server

Tags: java, eclipse, server, opc-ua, milo

Does the open source OPC UA Milo server support event based data sources? E.g. when the server sets sampling rate to 0 (zero) for a node (measuring point), would the server then produce all samples the event source produces? And if so where to look for an example or instruction how to achieve that?
The [example namespace](http://milo/milo-examples/server-examples/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/examples/server/ExampleNamespace.java) of the example server seem to add attribute delegates that are reactive, i.e. they only produce values when asked by the subscription mechanism to do so.

Answer (score 0):

A sampling interval of zero means use the "fastest practical rate", which can mean report by exception or event-based if the underlying source supports it, but in the case of the example namespace it's not supported.

An implementation of Namespace is free to handle that rate however it wants, including as event-based if the source actually supports it. A namespace is simply told when items have been created, modified, or deleted, and it's the implementation's responsibility to then start sampling those items at the requested rate. The SDK will take into account any MinimumSamplingInterval attribute the node has set on it before instructing the namespace to start sampling.

Comment: Oeps I missed your answer. Sorry.
That clarifies my thinkering how to go about! So if I set the minimum sampling rate to zero for a node, that would mean that the underlying datasource can produce data as fast as it can in a event-based way. Then the client has the option to subscribe to this node with a sampling interval of zero in the monitored items configuration.